# Debugging HTTP POST

Tags: php, android, http, post, mailto

I'm trying to execute a PHP script using a HTTP POST request. Here's my Android code that I use
in order to execute the POST.

```
        String url = "xxx";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        // set params
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("toEmail", toEmail));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("toName", toName));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fromEmail", email));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fromName", achternaam));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "Manual"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("job", jobId));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", voornaam));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", achternaam));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", tel));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", opmerkingen));

        HttpResponse response;
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        response = client.execute(post);
```

When I debug this code and go into the response itself the BasicStatusLine is: HTTP/1.1 200 OK. Which should
indicate that the PHP script was executed correctly right? Well, the script is supposed to do a mailto. This is the PHP script:

```
  <?php
    require_once('mail.php');
    require_once('Job.php');

  if (isset($_POST['toEmail'])) {
     sql_insert(array('content' => var_export($_POST, true), 'email' =>
     $_POST['toEmail'], 'type' => $_POST['type']), 'Apply');
     } else {
     sql_insert(array('content' => var_export($_POST, true), 'email' => 'no email',
     'type' => $_POST['type']), 'Apply');
    }

    if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'LinkedIn' && isset($_POST['job'])) {
            $to = 'HARDCODEDEMAIL'
            $from = array('email' => '', 'name' => '');
            $firstname = '';
            $lastname = '';
            $profile = '';
            $img = '';
            $headline = '';
            $location = '';
            $industry = '';
            $current = array();
            $past = array();
            $education = array();
            $recommendations = 0;
            $phone = '';
            $address = '';
            $twitter = array();

            if (isset($_POST['toEmail'])) {
                    $to['email'] = $_POST['toEmail'];
            }
            if (isset($_POST['toName'])) {
                    $to['name'] = $_POST['toName'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['fromEmail'])) {
                    $from['email'] = $_POST['fromEmail'];
            }
            if (isset($_POST['fromName'])) {
                    $from['name'] = $_POST['fromName'];
            }

            $job = new Job();
            $job->init($_POST['job']);

            if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
                    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
                    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['profile'])) {
                    $profile = $_POST['profile'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['img'])) {
                    $img = $_POST['img'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['headline'])) {
                    $headline = $_POST['headline'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
                    $location = $_POST['location'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['industry'])) {
                    $industry = $_POST['industry'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['current'])) {
                    $currentString = $_POST['current'];
                    $positions = explode("*_*", $currentString);
                    foreach ($positions as $positionString) {
                            $items = explode("**", $positionString);
                            if (count($items) > 0) {
                                    $position = array('title' => '', 'url' => '', 'company' => '');
                                    $position['title'] = $items[0];

                                    if (count($items) > 1) {
                                            $position['company'] = $items[1];

                                            if (count($items) > 2) {
                                                    $position['url'] = 'http://www.linkedin.com/company/' .  $items[2];
                                            }
                                    }

                                    $current[] = $position;
                            }
                    }
            }

            if (isset($_POST['past'])) {
                    $pastString = $_POST['past'];
                    $positions = explode("*_*", $pastString);
                    foreach ($positions as $positionString) {
                            $items = explode("**", $positionString);
                            if (count($items) > 0) {
                                    $position = array('title' => '', 'url' => '', 'company' => '');
                                    $position['title'] = $items[0];

                                    if (count($items) > 1) {
                                            $position['company'] = $items[1];

                                            if (count($items) > 2) {
                                                    $position['url'] = 'http://www.linkedin.com/company/' . $items[2];
                                            }
                                    }

                                    $past[] = $position;
                            }
                    }
            }

            if (isset($_POST['education'])) {
                    $educationsString = $_POST['education'];
                    $educations = explode("*_*", $educationsString);
                    foreach ($educations as $edu) {
                            $education[] = $edu;
                    }
            }

            if (isset($_POST['recommendations'])) {
                    $recommendations = $_POST['recommendations'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
                    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
                    $address = $_POST['address'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['twitter'])) {
                    $twitterString = $_POST['twitter'];
                    $accounts = explode("*_*", $twitterString);
                    foreach ($accounts as $account) {
                            $twitter[] = $account;
                    }
            }

            $mail = new Email();
            $mail->linkedIn($to, $from, $job, $firstname, $lastname, $profile, $img,
    $headline, $location, $industry, $current, $past, $education, $recommendations,
    $phone, $address, $twitter);
    } else if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'Manual' &&
    isset($_POST['job'])) {

            $to = array('email' => '', 'name' => '');
            $from = array('email' => '', 'name' => '');
            $firstname = '';
            $lastname = '';
            $phone = '';
            $email = '';
            $comment = '';

            if (isset($_POST['toEmail'])) {
                    $to['email'] = $_POST['toEmail'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['toName'])) {
                    $to['name'] = $_POST['toName'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['fromEmail'])) {
                    $from['email'] = $_POST['fromEmail'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['fromName'])) {
                    $from['name'] = $_POST['fromName'];
            }

            $job = new Job();

            $job->init($_POST['job']);

            if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
                    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
                    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
                    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
            }

            if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
                    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
            }

            $mail = new Email();
        var_dump($to);
            $mail->normal('HARDCODEDEMAIL', $from, $job, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $email,     $comment);
```

For testing purposes I've hardcoded an email adress into the PHP code. Is anyone able to spot my mistake here? If not: Are there techniques to test the php script with this specific HTTP post?

Comment: have you tried to execute a curl with the post params from a linux bash?

Comment: I'm going to try that right now, I'm not really familiar with web development on this level so I didn't know that tool existed. Is Linux necessary to use it?

Comment: I don't think the OK message means your script ran correctly just that the post actually posted. If the script is bad, you'll know because it won't do what you want.

Comment: OK I've tried running it in cURL, it says their is an unexpected $end on line 206: $mail->normal('timkranen@hotmail.com', $from, $job, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $email, $comment);

Comment: so you got the bug in your php script.

Comment: Dreamweaver seems to have some trouble with this: $mail->normal, the normal part isn't highlighted

Comment: Also have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: OK, I've fixed all the PHP errors and cURL executes the script without a problem, but I'm still not receiving mail.

Comment: is mail well configured on your system?